# is it possible to run symantec protection engine to run in docker container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, symantec

We want to run symantec protection engine to run in centos docker container and run them on kubernetes cluster.

major hurdles for this is to apply license, if any one tried this, please share details and experience.